How is it possible to create float variable in C++ that is less than min float value?
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    float x = std::numeric_limits<float>().min(); // x = 1.17549e-38
    float y = 1.17549e-39f; // I created a variable that is less than min float value. How is it possible?

    if(x < y)
        std::cout << "x < y" << std::endl;
    else if (x == y)
        std::cout << "x == y" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "y < x" << std::endl;
   
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // x = 1.17549e-38
    std::cout << y << std::endl; // y = 1.17549e-39. No errors, no warnings.

    return 0;
}

When I tried to:
float y = 1.17549e-46f;

I got the warning: floating constant truncated to zero

I created a variable that is less than min float value. How is it possible? -- When you debugged the code and inspected y, what value did you see?  For Visual C++ 2022, 1.175e-39#DEN is what is shown, meaning a Denormalized number

Try numeric_limits::denorm_min; that's the actual limit on small numbers. min only gives the smallest number with maximum floating point digits.

You may be interested in std::fpclassify.

You seem to have misunderstood the use of std::numeric_limits<float>::min().

Returns the minimum finite value representable by the numeric type T.

Any value less than this is considered to be a subnormal number. [wikipedia.org]
If a value is smaller than the smallest subnormal number, they underflow to zero. This is literally what they are.

They are a subset of numbers that fill the underflow gap around zero in floating-point arithmetic.

To get the lowest possible float, use std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest(). This will return a negative floating point number.

Ok, how can I created the positive value, that is less, than std::numeric_limits().min()?

You created a positive subnormal value.

A subnormal number has less precision than a regular floating point number.

Exactly @john! But they are still useful you know.
